# Flow: MIXED_DML_OPERATION: DML operation

Tags: visual-workflow, dml, dmlexception

I am trying to automatically add a User's Default Team to an Account record when a Checkbox field on the Account record is checked to 'True'. I am using a Flow for this but am getting the following error: MIXED_DML_OPERATION: DML operation.

Here is the Flow. It is a Record Triggered flow that only triggers when the Checkbox field is changed to 'True'.

[image]

Here I am getting the Account Owner's Default Team.
[image]

And here, I am creating the Account Team Member records.
[image]

I have also tried using a Scheduled Path to Create the Account Team Member records but this is also resulting in the same error message.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as adding a Pause element with a 0 minute delay before the Create Records element.